# Entity Framework : Right Outer Join throws NullException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
var list = DB.MODULE_USER_PAGE.SqlQuery("select * from MODULE_ADMIN a right outer join MODULE_USER_PAGE b on a.ID = b.ID and USERID = @id", new SqlParameter("@id", id))
                    .AsEnumerable().Select(c => new UserMenuViewModal
                    {

                        USERPAGE = c.MODULE_NORMAL_PAGE


                    }).ToList();
```

This above code throws

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

This is my parameter,where is passing to SqlServer.

```
exec sp_executesql N'select * from MODULE_ADMIN a right outer join MODULE_USER_PAGE b on a.ID = b.ID and USERID = @id',N'@id nvarchar(4)',@id=N'2430'
```

[image]

This is the result of my query if executed in sql server.

Am I getting this error because of the null value?

Comment: What parameter's value `@id`  is you passing in?

Comment: the id is actually USERID

Comment: this is what the code excuted "exec sp_executesql N'select * from MODULE_ADMIN a right outer join MODULE_USER_PAGE b on a.ID = b.ID and USERID = @id',N'@id nvarchar(4)',@id=N'2430'"

Answer (score 1):

if the first column of the result set was null,EF will return null objects.

So you should make sure using explicitly name the columns at first field.(like PK)

```
var list = DB.MODULE_USER_PAGE.SqlQuery("select b.ID,b.MODULE_NORMAL_PAGE from MODULE_ADMIN a right outer join MODULE_USER_PAGE b on a.ID = b.ID and USERID = @id", new SqlParameter("@id", id))
                                .AsEnumerable().Select(c => new UserMenuViewModal
                                {
                                    USERPAGE = c.MODULE_NORMAL_PAGE
                                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it out. My UserMenuViewModal has another property which is ADMINPAGE. And I want to set the value if MODULE_ADMIN.ID is not null. How to do it?

Comment: I think you can use `Inner join` instead of `right outer join`.
Make sure two tables are related.

Comment: if i use Inner join it will return one row only, so that, i wont get the MODULE_NORMAL_PAGE..

Comment: OK,you can try  "select b.*,a.* from MODULE_ADMIN a right outer join MODULE_USER_PAGE b on a.ID = b.ID and USERID = @id"
Just make sure first field is not null

Comment: Yeah .. its working now.. Thanks...but how to get the value from table MODULE_ADMIN to check the null value?

Comment: Add `where clause` on your sql statement  like  "select * from MODULE_ADMIN a right outer join MODULE_USER_PAGE b on a.ID = b.ID and USERID = @id WHERE xxx IS NOT NULL"

Comment: Or you can also check the value is `null` on c# code

Comment: how to check null value from MODULE_ADMIN becasue i use DB.MODULE_USER_PAGE

Comment: Did you want to check `MODULE_USER_PAGE` is not null?

Comment: Its okay man.. i figured it out. Now its working as I wanted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can defined the column in your query and add `ISNULL` to replace value with empty string instead of null.

```
var list = DB.MODULE_USER_PAGE.SqlQuery("SELECT 
                                            ISNULL(b.ID, '') [ID],
                                            ISNULL(b.MODULE_NORMAL_PAGE,'') [MODULE_NORMAL_PAGE]
                                        FROM 
                                            MODULE_ADMIN a 
                                            RIGHT OUTER JOIN MODULE_USER_PAGE b on a.ID = b.ID AND USERID = @id", new SqlParameter("@id", id))
                                .AsEnumerable().Select(c => new UserMenuViewModal
                                {
                                    USERPAGE = c.MODULE_NORMAL_PAGE
                                }).ToList();
```

Then you can check if `USERPAGE` has value by doing this:
`string.IsNullOrEmpty(USERPAGE)`

Comment: `var list = DB.MODULE_USER_PAGE.SqlQuery("select a.MODULE_NORMAL_PAGE, a.MODULE_ADMIN_PAGE, ISNULL(b.ID,'NULL') AS ID from MODULE_USER_PAGE a LEFT outer join MODULE_ADMIN b on a.ID = b.ID and USERID = @id", new SqlParameter("@id", id))
                        .AsEnumerable().Select(c => new UserMenuViewModal
                        {
                            ID = c.ID,
                            USERPAGE = c.MODULE_NORMAL_PAGE,
                            ADMINPAGE = c.MODULE_ADMIN_PAGE


                        }).DefaultIfEmpty().ToList();`

Comment: just put '' instead of 'NULL', it will contain NULL string value if you do it like that....

Comment: what is NULL string value?

Comment: it will show literal value "NULL" instead of empty string "".